# AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'session'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am creating an endpoint that will effect a reversal using fastApi with python.I have an endpoint that takes in an id via post request & calls a reverse function on the transaction model. But I get the error AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'session' on 'db.session.add(transaction)' . I am not sure where this is coming from.

**Transaction model**

```
class Transaction(Base):
    __tablename__ = "transactions"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    uuid = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), nullable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    amount = Column(Numeric(18, 2))
    type = Column(
        Enum(TransactionTypes, name="transaction_trans_types"), nullable=False
    )
    wallet_type = Column(
        Enum(WalletTypes, name="transaction_wallet_types"), nullable=False
    )
    created_when = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    payment_ref = Column(String, nullable=False)
    running_balance = Column(Numeric(18, 2))
    currency = Column(String, default="KES")
    notes = Column(String)
    paid_by = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("patients.uuid"), nullable=True,)
    patient_uuid = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("patients.uuid"))
    wallet_uuid = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("wallets.uuid"))
    paid_by_names = Column(String)

    def reverse(self,db: Session,notes:str =None,):
        transaction =Transaction(amount =self.amount,type= self.type,wallet_type = self.wallet_type,payment_ref = self.payment_ref,
        notes= notes )
        
        db.session.add(transaction)
        db.session.commit()
        db.session.refresh(transaction)

        reversal = Reversal(transaction_uuid=transaction.uuid,reversed_transaction_uuid= self.reversed_transaction_uuid)
        db.session.add(reversal)
        db.session.commit()
        db.session.refresh(reversal)

        return transaction
```

**Reversal Model**

```
class Reversal(Base):
    __tablename__ = "reversals"  
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    transaction_uuid = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("transactions.uuid"))
    reversed_transaction_uuid = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True),ForeignKey("transactions.uuid"))

    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint("reversed_transaction_uuid"),
    )
```

**Endpoint**

```
@router.post("/{transaction_id}/reverse",)   
async def reverse_transaction(
    *,
    db: Session = Depends(deps.get_db),
    transaction_id: int,
    current_user: models.User = Depends(deps.get_current_active_user),
) -> Any:
    """
    Reverse transaction
    """ 
    if not current_user.is_superuser:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
            detail="Not allowed to reverse transactions",
        )
    try:
        transaction = (
            db.query(Transaction).filter(Transaction.id == transaction_id).scalar()
        )
   
        transaction.reverse(db,transaction)
    except NoResultFound:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail="Not found",
        )    

    return transaction
```

This is my deps.db

```
def get_db() -> Generator:
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The most important part would be to see how `deps.get_db()` looks like.

But according to your type hints I guess, this already gives you a Session. So instead of `db.session` in your `reverse` method, simply use `db`.

Comment: I have added my deps.db